# Mysql fetch assoc with PHP MYSQL in a table format

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I have a code like this.

## Code:

```
        <?php
        $book_query = mysql_query("select * from book_master')");
        while($book_query_fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($book_query)){
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($book_query_fetch);  
        echo "</pre>"
        }
        ?>
```

## Output:

```
        Array
        (
        [Book_Name] => Book1
        [Book_ID] => 123
        )

        Array
        (
        [Book_Name] => Book2
        [Book_ID] => 124
        )
```

## Expected Output: (in a table)

```
        Book Name       Book_ID
        Book1           123
        Book2           124
```

How can I achieve this?
EDIT:
The header part is a dynamic load. so i need the table header also in a loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know where you stuck doing that, but you can do below,

```
 echo "<table>";
 $i = 0;
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($book_query))
  {
     if($i == 0){
        $columns = array_keys($row);
        echo "<th>";
        foreach($columns as $column){
            echo "<td> $column</td>";
        }
        echo "</th>";
     }
     echo'<tr>';
     echo '<td>'.$row['Book_Name'].'</td>';
     echo '<td>'.$row['Book_ID'].'</td>';
     echo '</tr>';
     $i++;
  }
  echo "</table>";
```

**Waring:** [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: oh no. the fetch assoc is a dynamic one with values.. i need a dynamic for table header part also.

Comment: See my updated. Note: I haven't tested the code, it's just an idea.

Comment: rikesh - please check my other question here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22786306/php-mysql-associate-array-and-table

Comment: Will look into it but Kindly [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer if your problem is solved by this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
 <?php
        $book_query = mysql_query("select * from book_master')");
echo "<table>";
echo"<tr><td>Book Name</td><td>Book_ID</td></tr>";        
while($book_query_fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($book_query)){

echo"<tr><td>".$book_query_fetch['Book_Name']."</td><td>".$book_query_fetch['Book_ID']."</td></tr>"; 


        }
echo "</table>";
        ?>
```

Comment: sunny - i have edited my question. the table header part ie. Book Name and Book_ID will change dynamically. so the header part also should be loaded using the $book_query. please help me

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
<table>

<?php
        $book_query = mysql_query("select * from book_master')");
       $book_query_fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($book_query); ?>
          <th>
          <td><?php echo $book_query_fetch['book_name']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $book_query_fetch['Book_ID']; ?> </td>
         </th>
     <?php    while($book_query_fetch){ ?>
     <tr>
    <td><?php echo $book_query_fetch['Book_Name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $book_query_fetch['Book_ID']; ?></td>
     </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Mohit - the header part is dynamic. sorry for my bad english
<th>
 <td>Book Name </td>
 <td>Book ID </td>
 </th>
This will change dynamically. so i don't want to hardcode this value. any help

Answer (score 0):

Along with Rikesh's code, Use the array_keys() function. this will fetch all the keys of the subset array.

So you can fetch the keys also dynamically.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($book_query))
  {
     echo'<tr><th>'.
   $columns = array_keys($row);
    foreach($columns as $column){
        echo "<td> $column</td>";
    }
     .'</th></tr><tr>';
     echo '<td>'.$row['Book_Name'].'</td>';
     echo '<td>'.$row['Book_ID'].'</td>';
     echo '</tr>';
  }
  echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Sagar - Thanks . please check my other question here. help me out.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22786306/php-mysql-associate-array-and-table

Answer (score 0):

```
//try this      
  <?php
        $book_query = mysql_query("select * from book_master')");
        while($book_query_fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($book_query)){
        echo "<pre>";
$a="<table><tr>";

foreach ($book_query_fetch as $key=>$value){
        $a="<th>".$key."</th>"
}
exit;
        }
$a="</tr>"



       while($book_query_fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($book_query)){

$a="<tr>";

foreach ($book_query_fetch as $key=>$value){
        $a="<td>".$value."</td>"
}
$a="</tr>";
        }

 $a="</table>"

echo $a;       


?>
```

Comment: check this one it will help you!